# Django Optimiztion

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have query written in  raw sql in Django..
Suppose the result of that query is assigned to a variable ***queryResult***.

I then loop this ***queryResult***, then retrive data from almost three tables using django ORM.

For example..

```
for item in queryResult:
   a=table1.objects.get(id=item[0])
   b=table2.objects.get(id=item[1])
   c=table2.objects.get(id=item[2])
   z=a.result
   x=a.result1
   v=c.result

   ####based on some condition check the data is stored into a list as dictionary.

   recentDocsList.append({'PurchaseType':item[0],
                           'CaseName':z,
                           'DocketNumber':x, 
                           'CourtID':item[2],                             
                           'PacerCmecf':v,                              
                           'DID':item[3]})
```

After completing the loop this recentDocsList is returned back...
But the entire thing is making my to page render slowly. Anybody has any method to resolve this issue.

PS: The entire thing is inside a while loop. At a time only 50 results are retrieved. The control comes out of the while loop if the result retrieved is less  than 50 or the
**recentDocsList** length is equal to 10.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

#### Don't optimize too early - this can create obfuscation and confusion.

Even using SQLite3 you should be able to pull 50 chained querysets without taxing the DB (upping to a higher performance DB like PostgreSQL would improve this further). This would suggest that your problem is elsewhere, to debug this try calling your models / queries / views in

```
$ ./manage.py debugshell
```

and this will print out your SQL queries so you can see what is actually being called. Even better would be to install [django-debug-toolbar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar) as this would inform you where the SQL / rendering slow downs are.

But! Unless you have a really good reason to do so, **DON'T WRITE CUSTOM SQL** to be executed in django - the ORM can take care of almost everything. Some of the dangers of custom SQL include terrible performance - as you're probably experiencing.

Further - a `while` loop in a performance sensitive place (like page rendering) sounds like a disaster waiting to happen - are you sure you can't rewrite this in a safer way?

Without seeing more code it's difficult to help - how large are your query sets? Are they efficient? Do you have indexes to your tables? (Django will provide these if you allow it, but it sounds like you're doing something different).